# Trouble synchronizing Filters

Tags: android, filter, android-alertdialog, android-adapter

I have implemented several `Filter` Types and they work fine when I select them in an `AlertDialog` (MultiChoice) and I save this selection for future uses, i.e. if I again open the app but in this case, it just works the last filter.

The aspect looks like this

[image]

The selected criteria are fine saved and the selection in `AlertDialog` reflects inmediately Filter Buttons (Crop Year... und Crop Type) and the click on these Buttons to delete that Filter Criterium reflects as well and therefore I ask here, because, when I click/mark an option and the other one in `AlertDialog`is the filtered Data available to the next Filter/Unfilter Operation.

The anomaly happens when I want to initialize the elements with previously selected criteria (As said, they are correct).

I tried to introduce delay between those two filters, in order that the filtered Data of first Filter are available as input for the second filter but I get identical results.

Relevant Code is here

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.farm_fields_list);
    // Get SharedPreferences
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext()); 


    selected = getSelectedCriteria();

    ...



    // Retrieve Session
     session                 = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext()); 
     Log.i("TAG", "FarmListActivity::onCreate:: 1");
    // Get the Parameter
    Intent intent            = getIntent();

    Bundle bundle            = intent.getExtras();

    if ( bundle != null) {
        farms                = (ArrayList<Object>)bundle.get(Constants.FARMS);      
    }

    farm_field_exp_list_view.setDividerHeight(2);
    farm_field_exp_list_view.setGroupIndicator(null);
    farm_field_exp_list_view.setClickable(true);


    /** Adapter initialisieren **/
    myFarmAdapter = new MyFarmAdapter(FarmListActivity.this, farms, mapView);

    farm_field_exp_list_view.setAdapter(myFarmAdapter);     



    /** Filter Buttons initialisieren **/
    initializeFilterButton(crop_type_button, Constants._CROP_TYPE_MAIS_CRITERIUM, 0); // <- At this point
    initializeFilterButton(crop_year_button, Constants._CROP_YEAR_2015_CRITERIUM, 1);


    /**         **/     

    // Button
    show_fields_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.show_map_btn);
    show_fields_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // We'll pass as parameter an ArrayList of field_guids, whose fields will be shown
            ArrayList<String> selectedFields = myFarmAdapter.getSelectedFields();
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra(Constants.SELECTED_FIELDS, selectedFields);

            // --------------------------
            activity.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
            activity.finish();              

        }

    });
    //

}

private void initializeFilterButton(final Button filter_button, final String filter_criterium, final int pos) {

    // First we check whether buttons can be initialized via SharedPreferences - selected


    if ( selected != null ){
        filter_button.setVisibility(selected[pos] ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        if (selected[pos]) {
            myFarmAdapter.getFilter().filter(filter_criterium);
        }

    }

    // I we click, then we remove the filter
    filter_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {                
            // Unset Filter Type F1 is the same like filter the original Data with the other Filters (if present) 

            myFarmAdapter.getFilter().filter(Constants._REMOVE_CRITERIUM+filter_criterium);
            filter_button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            selected[pos] = false;
            settings.put(Constants._SELECTED_CRITERIA, Arrays.toString(selected));

            session.createOrUpdateSettings(settings);


    }});    

}

@Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // action with ID action_filter was selected
        case R.id.action_filter: 
            Dialogs.showFilterDialog(this, session, myFarmAdapter, appliedFilterTV, crop_year_button, crop_type_button);
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Filter selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
        default:
        break;
    }

    return true;
  }
```

And the relevant part if my Class `Dialogs`

```
    public static void showFilterDialog(final FarmListActivity farmListActivity, final SessionManager session, final MyFarmAdapter myFarmAdapter, 
                                        final TextView tView, final Button crop_year_button, final Button crop_type_name_button) {

        settings                              = session.getSettings();

        String[] filter_menu = farmListActivity.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.filter_menu);

        selected = new boolean[filter_menu.length];
        if ( settings.containsKey(Constants._SELECTED_CRITERIA)) {
            selected = parseBooleanStringToBooleanArray(settings.get(Constants._SELECTED_CRITERIA));

        } else {

            Arrays.fill(selected, false);
        }

        yes                                    = false;

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(farmListActivity);     
        // set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(R.string.title_choice_filter);


        alertDialogBuilder.setMultiChoiceItems(R.array.filter_menu, selected, new OnMultiChoiceClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked ) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int visibility          = 0;
                String[] filters        = farmListActivity.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.filter_menu);
                int filters_size        = filters.length;

                String filter_criterium = "";


                selected[which]  = isChecked;

                filter_criterium = filters[which];

                // If checked, remove selected criterium
                filter_criterium = isChecked ? filter_criterium : Constants._REMOVE_CRITERIUM + filter_criterium;

                // Filter 
                myFarmAdapter.getFilter().filter(filter_criterium);

                // Here we save the selected criterium
                settings.put(Constants._SELECTED_CRITERIA, Arrays.toString(selected));

                // Here we update button visibility
                visibility = isChecked ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE;

                // Activate the Filter Buttons
                if ( filter_criterium.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants._CROP_YEAR_2015_CRITERIUM)) {
                    crop_year_button.setVisibility(visibility);
                }

                if ( filter_criterium.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants._CROP_TYPE_MAIS_CRITERIUM)) {
                    crop_type_name_button.setVisibility(visibility);                        
                }       


                settings.put(Constants._SELECTED_CRITERIA, Arrays.toString(selected));

                session.createOrUpdateSettings(settings);

            }});
        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        // create alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        for ( int i = 0; i < selected.length; i++)
            alertDialog.getListView().setItemChecked(i, selected[i]);
        // show it
        alertDialog.show();         
    }
```

And last my Log

```
02-17 11:30:49.694: I/TAG(10211): FarmListActivity::initializeFilterButton::BEGIN filter_criterium: Year(Current Year: 2015) pos: 1 selected: [true, true]
02-17 11:30:49.694: I/TAG(10211): FarmListActivity::initializeFilterButton::if (selected[pos]) {
02-17 11:30:49.696: I/TAG(10211): MyFarmAdapter::getFilter:: fieldFilter: com.nutiteq.advancedmap.MyFarmAdapter$FieldFilter@ebe6c48
02-17 11:30:49.699: I/TAG(10211): FieldFilter::performFiltering:: constraint: [Year(Current Year: 2015)] constraintsList: []
02-17 11:30:49.699: I/TAG(10211): FarmListActivity::initializeFilterButton::END filter_criterium: Year(Current Year: 2015) pos: 1 selected: [true, true]
02-17 11:30:49.699: I/TAG(10211): FieldFilter::performFiltering:: constraint: [Year(Current Year: 2015)] #fields of filteredItems: 35 #fields of parentItems: 35
02-17 11:30:49.699: I/TAG(10211): FarmListActivity::initializeFilterButton::BEGIN filter_criterium: Crop(Current Crop: Mais) pos: 0 selected: [true, true]
02-17 11:30:49.699: I/TAG(10211): FarmListActivity::initializeFilterButton::if (selected[pos]) {
02-17 11:30:49.699: I/TAG(10211): MyFarmAdapter::getFilter:: fieldFilter: com.nutiteq.advancedmap.MyFarmAdapter$FieldFilter@ebe6c48
02-17 11:30:49.699: I/TAG(10211): FarmListActivity::initializeFilterButton::END filter_criterium: Crop(Current Crop: Mais) pos: 0 selected: [true, true]
02-17 11:30:49.699: I/TAG(10211): MyFarmAdapter::FieldFilter::filterByCropYear:: crop_year: 2015
02-17 11:30:49.700: I/TAG(10211): MyFarmAdapter::FieldFilter::filterByCropYear::fields.size: 35
02-17 11:30:49.700: I/TAG(10211): FieldFilter::performFiltering:: AFTER filtering:: constraint: Year(Current Year: 2015) #fields of filteredItems: 35 #fields of parentItems: 35
02-17 11:30:49.700: I/TAG(10211): FieldFilter::performFiltering:: constraint: [Crop(Current Crop: Mais)] constraintsList: [Year(Current Year: 2015)]
02-17 11:30:49.700: I/TAG(10211): FieldFilter::performFiltering:: constraint: [Crop(Current Crop: Mais)] #fields of filteredItems: 35 #fields of parentItems: 35
02-17 11:30:49.704: I/TAG(10211): MyFarmAdapter::FieldFilter::filterByCropTypeName::fields.size: 35
02-17 11:30:49.704: I/TAG(10211): FieldFilter::performFiltering:: AFTER filtering:: constraint: Crop(Current Crop: Mais) #fields of filteredItems: 35 #fields of parentItems: 35
02-17 11:30:49.771: I/TAG(10211): FieldFilter::publishResults:: constraint: Year(Current Year: 2015) #fields of filteredItems: 11 #fields of parentItems: 35
02-17 11:30:49.772: I/TAG(10211): FieldFilter::publishResults:: constraint: Crop(Current Crop: Mais) #fields of filteredItems: 10 #fields of parentItems: 35
```

As you can see in Log File, `publishResults` Methods set Data available too late and I don't know how I can solve without dellegated Events, there must be a simpler solution.

In case of `AlertDialog` I can log it and the correct sequence appears as follows

```
1. performFiltering of first Filter
2. publishResults of first Filter
3. performFiltering of second Filter
4. publishResults of second Filter
```

Comment: Your question it's kind of ambiguous but shouldn't you be concatenating the filters in onCreate like you do in the dialog? If you call initializeFilterButton() two times isn't it normal that you'll end up filtering only after the last call?

Comment: I have discovered another `filter()` Calling with a FilterListener and there I must implement the `onFilterComplete` Method. When I implement, I tell you. By the way, the concatenating of filters in case of selecting individual in alert dialog works fine.

Comment: Luks, I save Filters State in SharedPreferences and I load them every time I initialize this Activity, so I perform this Filter Operation as well from Dialog as from onCreate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve it and just as I said to @Luksprog , I implemented the Methods of `FilterListener` Interface in my Activity, in this case `public void onFilterComplete(int count)` as follows

```
@Override
public void onFilterComplete(int count) {

    if ( ! isTrue(initialisedButtons) ) 
        initializeFilterButton(crop_year_button, Constants._CROP_YEAR_2015_CRITERIUM, 1);

}

private boolean isTrue(boolean[] initialisedButtons) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    boolean result = true;

    if ( initialisedButtons != null && initialisedButtons.length>0 ) {
        for ( int i = 0; i<initialisedButtons.length && result; i++)
            result = result && initialisedButtons[i];
    } else
        result = false;

    return result;
}
```

I inserted in `onFilterComplete` Method the line

```
initializeFilterButton(crop_year_button, Constants._CROP_YEAR_2015_CRITERIUM, 1);
```

and modified `initializeFilterButton` like this

```
private void initializeFilterButton(final Button filter_button, final String filter_criterium, final int pos) {

    // First we check whether buttons can be initialized via SharedPreferences - selected


    if ( selected != null ){
        filter_button.setVisibility(selected[pos] ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        if (selected[pos]) {

            myFarmAdapter.getFilter().filter(filter_criterium, this);           
        } else {
            // Neccessary if the filter is disabled in order to fire FilterListener onFilterComplete. That's a NO Filter Operation
            myFarmAdapter.getFilter().filter("", this);         
        }
        // To ensure, we initialize this button.
        initialisedButtons[pos] = true;
    }


    filter_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {                
            // Unset Filter Type F1 is the same like filter the original Data with the other Filters (if present) 
        myFarmAdapter.getFilter().filter(Constants._REMOVE_CRITERIUM+filter_criterium);
            filter_button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            selected[pos] = false;
            settings.put(Constants._SELECTED_CRITERIA, Arrays.toString(selected));              
            session.createOrUpdateSettings(settings);
    }});    
}
```

And just like this, we can perform several Filter Operations **sequentially**.